# How to find the word directly after a special character and before a number using regular expressions in python?

Tags: python, regex, string

For example, I would like to get the word right after the special character `")"` and right before the number in this string:

```
{"1) PINK Victoria's Secret 82.3% 93.7% 79.3% 85.1% 34) Gucci 67.8% 87.3% 44.6% 66.6% 67) Lilly Pulitzer 58.3% 43.7% 45.6% 49.2%": ''}
```

The result should be PINK Victoria's Secret, Gucci, Lilly Pulitzer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with the following `regex`:

```
\)\s*(\D+)\s\d
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/kL8lG1/2)

Explanation:

```
\)           - Match a closing parens
\s*          - Match 0 or more spaces
(\D+)    - Match 1 or more non-digit characters
\s\d        - Match a space followed by a digit
```

Answer (score 0):

You also can use this:

```
\)(.*?)[\d]
```